# Helm install istio/gateway as single package

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio, istio-gateway

I was trying to install base/istiod/gateway via helm as a single package using dependency chart. I have added dependencies (istiod/base) in gateway chart and imported the dependencies through command `helm dependencies build`

Chart.yaml

```
name: gateway
.
.
dependencies:
  - name: base
    repository: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
  - name: istiod
    repository: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
```

Since gateway have some dependencies from istiod chart and gateway and istiod are running in parallel, installation is failing. Is there any possibilities in helm for maintaining order of chart installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is not this option.  Helm dependencies do not describe other components that need to be installed before this one, and there is no ordering of dependencies.  Instead, the dependencies are combined with the current chart and everything is installed at the same time.

Since Istio is a cluster-level component, it doesn't make sense to install it as part of your application.  It will not work if you break your application into two separate services and both install Istio as their own dependency, for example.  I would have your cluster administrator install Istio in the normal way, and then include Istio resources in your chart, without specifically mentioning Istio as a dependency.

Comment: You had initially tagged the question with [tag:helmfile], but the question just mentions plain Helm.  If you are using the separate Helmfile tool, its [`needs:`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dag-aware-installationdeletion-ordering-with-needs) directive probably does what you're looking for.